# Prepros failed to process Sass file version "GLIBCXX_3.4.20" not found on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sass, ubuntu-14.04, prepros

To learn and use Sass, I installed **Prepros** On **Ubuntu 14.04** LTS. But every time i try to process an scss file (sass file) I get this error notification

```
Failed to Process File sass/style.scss
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6:
version "GLIBCXX_3.4.20" not found
(required by /usr/lib/prepros/resources/extensions/node-sass.asar.unpacked/node-modules/node-sass/build/Release/binding.node)
```

I checked using `stings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX` and confirmed that indeed it seems GLIBCXX versions are only available up to 3.4.19. Is there a way to install version 3.4.20 (and higher) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? or a workaround for either that or using Prepros? or using SASS in general?

Please keep in mind I've installed a lot of very version specific software and I'm very reluctant about upgrading. Any help would be really highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> version "GLIBCXX_3.4.20" not found

The problem is that your `libstdc++.so.6` is too old.

Versions of `libstdc++` and their ABI's are documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html). `GLIBCXX_3.4.19` corresponds to GCC-4.8.3, and `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` to GCC-4.9.0.

To get a newer `libstdc++.so.6`, you need to upgrade your GCC. [Here](https://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Upgrade_to_gcc_4.9) is how this could be done.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually found an alternative standalone compiler (scout app) that works fine... Plus I decided to look into gulp, another great option too. Thanks for the help though, much appreciated