# How to change/ upgrade my GLIBCXX in centos

Tags: centos, libstdc++

ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found
I encountered this error while installing python package(fbprophet) in my system

My environment details:
Centos:7
GCC version:8.3.0

```
strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH'''
```

How to get/upgrade my GLIBC to GLIBCXX_3.4.20

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prepros failed to process Sass file version "GLIBCXX\_3.4.20" not found on Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367513/prepros-failed-to-process-sass-file-version-glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-on-ubuntu)

Comment: In ubuntu even GLIBCXX is available for higher versions. But in case of centos repository itself maximum GLIBCXX available is 3.4.19 irrespective of higher gcc version. For your information i am having GCC 8.3.0 in my system

Answer (score 0):

To set up

```
yum -y install centos-release-scl

yum -y install devtoolset-8-gcc devtoolset-8-gcc++
```

(or just yum install devtoolset-8)

```
source /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/enable
```